# Looking for OpenAi's Codex like opensource sandbox playground

Tags: python, sandbox, openai-api

I'm looking for OpenAi's codex like sandbox where I can test my custom trained Large Language model. Best if sandbox is for python code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you want a sandbox where you can run code for deep learning.

You can use Google Colaboratory for this purpose.

Also provide more details in case I misinterpreted your question.

Comment: I can rephrase in a way that I have an application that automatically generate Python code. At the time I needed a sandbox that can compile Python's code and the core purpose is to ensure that if somehow it generates a malicious code it shouldn't effect but is confined to the premisis of sandbox.